# Simulation of Cox processes with self-dependent intensity

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process, simulation

A [Cox Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox_process) $X_t$ is, in a nutshell, a Poisson process whose intensity $\lambda_t$ is a stochastic process itself. If  $\lambda_t$ is independent from $X_t$ and it's possible to sample, then one can simulate $X_t$ generating first a trajectory $\lambda^0_t$ of $\lambda_t$ and then simulate a non-homogeneous Poisson process with intensity $\lambda^0_t$ (see [here](http://prac.im.pwr.edu.pl/~hugo/publ/HSC_03_4_BurneckiHaerdleRWeron.pdf) for example, page 3) by thinning.

My question is: how can one simulate $X_t$ if $\lambda_t$ depends on $X_t$ (and so we cannot sample $\lambda_t$)?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a little more specific example of what the dependence looks like?

Comment: Hi @icurays1, sure. The full problem is as follows:

$X_t$ and $Y_t$ are Cox processes with intensities $\lambda_t$ and $\mu_t$ respectively. Let $a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{R})$, $a,b > 0$ and $d,e > -1$. Then  $\lambda_t = a\cdot(1+c \cdot \mathbf{1}_{X_t<Y_t})$  and  $\mu_t = b\cdot(1+d \cdot \mathbf{1}_{X_t > Y_t})$.